# "else" completes even if "if" is true

Tags: c#, if-statement, split, line, translate

I'm messing with some kind of dictionary, that is supposed to translate words from one textbox to other, and the other way around, but It doesn't act as I'd like it to. The code for the button is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:/words.txt");
        int i = 0;
        var items = from line in lines
                    where i++ != 0
                    let words = line.Split('|')
                    where words.Count() > 1
                    select new
                    {
                        word = words[0],
                        translation = words[1]
                    };

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == item.word)
            {
                textBox2.Text = item.translation;
            }
            if (textBox2.Text == item.translation)
            {
                textBox1.Text = item.word;
            }
            else
            {
                label3.Text = ("not found");
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit: Doesn't work with "else if" either.

Comment: You should tag your question with the language you are using.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would help if you state which language you use. And the tags `split` and `translate` do not seem to be appropiate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it best to avoid if statements where possible, and I especially try to avoid else and else if. The reason for this is that it simply gets confusing when there are multiple conditions to try and follow. Here is possibly a cleaner way to understand what is going on and also solve your issue.

```
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == item.word)
            {
                textBox2.Text = item.translation;
                continue;  // Don't process anything else in this loop.
            }
            if (textBox2.Text == item.translation)
            {
                textBox1.Text = item.word;
                continue;  // Don't process anything else in this loop.
            }
            label3.Text = ("not found");
        }
```

Since we don't want any other logic to execute (my assumption) if one of our if statements is true, we simply use *continue* to skip the rest of the logic in the foreach and move to the next item.

Why is this in a loop anyway? Won't the text in the first iteration be overwritten by subsequent iterations?

Comment: @MátéBurján What exactly doesn't work? Are you always seeing "not found?" That could be because, in this scenario, you'll always be analyzing the last item in items, and therefore possibly always hitting the "not found" condition. If you want to stop after finding a hit, replace the *continue* statements with *break* statements. A loop like this doesn't make much sense, which could be your main problem.

Comment: Yes, it always writes "not found", even if it finds a translation. I've tried "break" too, it didn't work either. Should I make it to stop at the last line somehow?

Comment: Did you try *break* in *both* spots? Try removing the label3 line as a test. Does it work then?

Comment: By the way, why are you looping and immediately replacing the textbox values with the next iteration of the loop? You'll only ever get the last value.

Comment: Now that you mention it, that could be the problem. Do you have any idea how to make it work both ways with only one buton?

Comment: I don't know what it is that you're trying to accomplish. I think we've moved beyond this actual question though. It would probably be good if you accepted an answer here. If you need further help, with a new question (and it appears that is the case), it probably makes sense to first try and work through it, now that you understand the issue, then possibly post another question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 6):

You need an `else if`, otherwise the else is only happening from the second if:

```
  if (textBox1.Text == item.word)
  {
     textBox2.Text = item.translation;
  }
  else if (textBox2.Text == item.translation)
  {
     textBox1.Text = item.word;
  }
  else
  {
     label3.Text = ("not found");
  }
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `else if` instead of `elseif`?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `else if (textBox2.Text == item.translation)` instead of `if (textBox2.Text == item.translation)`.

`ELSE IF`!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see it is that there's no else if, that second if will only work if the first if is true. Try this:

```
foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text = item.word)
        {
            textBox2.Text = item.translation;
        }

        else if (textBox2.Text = item.translation)
        {
            textBox1.Text = item.word;
        }
        else
        {
            label3.Text = ("not found");
        }
    }
```